# i have two div that i want first appear top of second in html and second div attributes cant be changed

Tags: css

I have two `div` elements, and I can't change the second `div`'s attributes.

I want the first `div` to appear on top of the `second` div, and the second `div` should remain behind it.

```css
.second{
    height: 100px;
    background: #000 !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    float: right !important;
    padding-top: 6px !important;
    visibility: inherit !important}
    
.first{
   /* what must be here? */
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    attributes of this div can be changed 
</div>

<div class="second">
    attributes of this div cant be changed
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the z-index property + same padding and .second:

```
.first{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owOxBg)

Comment: Are you sure you used the code correctly? The first div should go above the second div since z-index is 1 (not -1). Add "background-color: white;" to above code to see which text is above the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
.first {
   /* what must be here? */
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
     height: 100px;
     position: absolute;
     padding-top: 6px;
     width:100%;
     color: red;
     z-index:2;
}
```

```css
.second{
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(0,255,0,0.2);
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    float: right !important;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
    visibility: inherit !important;
    z-index:1;
  }
    
.first {
   /* what must be here? */
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
     height: 100px;
     position: absolute;
     padding-top: 6px;
     width:100%;
     color: red;
     z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 Div1 
</div>

<div class="second">
    Div 2  Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2
</div>
```

Comment: use of z-index:2; for `.first`